# SqlDataAdapter RowUpdating Event Seems to Mutate Update Command

Tags: .net, datatable, sqldataadapter, sqlcommandbuilder

I followed [a tutorial](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/spike/archive/2009/12/11/how-to-see-the-sql-executing-when-updating-a-dataset-via-dataadapter-update.aspx) to use the .Net SqlDataAdapater.Update method to generate a table update script. However, it appears that somewhere along the way the SqlCommands are getting mutated in such a way as to be syntactically incorrect. What is even stranger to me is that this problem seems to have popped up out of nowhere.

```
...
dataAdapter.RowUpdating += (sender, updatingEvent) => AppendToTableDataString(updatingEvent, tableDataStringBuilder);
var cmdBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(dataAdapter);
dataAdapter.DeleteCommand = cmdBuilder.GetDeleteCommand();
dataAdapter.InsertCommand = cmdBuilder.GetInsertCommand();
dataAdapter.UpdateCommand = cmdBuilder.GetUpdateCommand();
Console.WriteLine("Before call to Update: " + dataAdapter.UpdateCommand.CommandText);
dataAdapter.Update(DataTable);
Console.WriteLine("After call to Update: " + dataAdapter.UpdateCommand.CommandText);
...

private static void AppendToTableDataString(SqlRowUpdatingEventArgs updatingEvent, StringBuilder tableDataBuilder)
{
  if (updatingEvent.Command == null)
  {
    return;
  }

  Console.WriteLine("Before appending to StringBuilder: " + updatingEvent.Command.CommandText);
            tableDataBuilder.Append(updatingEvent.Command.Parameters.Cast<SqlParameter>()
                                    .Aggregate(updatingEvent.Command.CommandText, (current, aParameter) =>
                                               current.Replace(aParameter.ParameterName, aParameter.Value.ToString())) + Environment.NewLine);
  Console.WriteLine("After appending to StringBuilder: " + updatingEvent.Command.CommandText);
}
```

Output:

```
Before call to Update: UPDATE [schema].[table] SET [Id] = @p1, [Num] = @p2 WHERE (([Id] = @p3) AND ((@p4 = 1 AND [Num] IS NULL) OR ([Num] = @p5)))
Before appending to StringBuilder: UPDATE [schema].[table] SET [Id] = @p1, [Num] = @p2 WHERE (([Id] = @p3) AND ((@p4 = 1 AND [Num] IS NULL) OR ([Num] = @p5)))
After appending to StringBuilder: UPDATE [schema].[table] SET [Id] = @p1, [Num] = @p2 WHERE (([Id] = @p3) AND ((@p4 = 1 AND [Num] IS NULL) OR ([Num] = @p5)))
Before appending to StringBuilder: UPDATE [schema].[table] WHERE (([Id] = @p1) AND ((@p2 = 1 AND [Num] IS NULL) OR ([Num] = @p3)))
After appending to StringBuilder: UPDATE [schema].[table] WHERE (([Id] = @p1) AND ((@p2 = 1 AND [Num] IS NULL) OR ([Num] = @p3)))
Before appending to StringBuilder: UPDATE [schema].[table] WHERE (([Id] = @p1) AND ((@p2 = 1 AND [Num] IS NULL) OR ([Num] = @p3)))
After appending to StringBuilder: UPDATE [schema].[table] WHERE (([Id] = @p1) AND ((@p2 = 1 AND [Num] IS NULL) OR ([Num] = @p3)))
After call to Update: UPDATE [schema].[table] WHERE (([Id] = @p1) AND ((@p2 = 1 AND [Num] IS NULL) OR ([Num] = @p3)))
```

So you can see that the problem is that an incorrect script is being generated:

```
UPDATE [schema].[table] WHERE (([Id] = @p1) AND ((@p2 = 1 AND [Num] IS NULL) OR ([Num] = @p3)))
```

The output makes it look like the command is getting mutated somewhere *after* the first row update finishes executing, but *before* the second row update, however, I have no idea what would be causing this to happen. Can anyone offer any clues or spot what I'm doing wrong? As I indicate above, this was working fine and then seemingly seemed to break w/o reason.

UPDATE

I completely removed the StringBuilder operations (the RowUpdating event consisted *solely* of printing out the updating command), and I still saw the weird behavior.

*However*, I believe I was able to mitigate the problem by moving things around in my code a bit. Among other things, I set the RowUpdating event *after* setting the various commands on the adapter. I guess I'm not sure *why* this is affecting the problem (hence, I'm not listing this as an answer), but it appears to be fixing things for now at least.